# content hidden but not breaking line

Tags: html, css, fixed

I would like to  create a div container with fixed width and height of 100px and it should work like a window.

Then in addition

- It should have content divs into it next to each other 'floating' left, not breaking into a new line.
- The container should hide all what is longer as it width or height.

Do I have to use

```
overflow:hidden
```

?

fiddle here:

```
container and content
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hd8Bm/1/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What I want is a Porsche. Can you help ? What have you tried Marius ?

Comment: Can you show us examples of code and exactly what is the expected output? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: my question is: How can I achieve having each content next to each other NOT breaking into a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is what the CSS needs to be like:

```
#container
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.content
{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/HB8kB/

The trick is done by white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Nice answer. However, note that white-space inherits. So if you don't want to have the innermost divs to have `nowrap` as well, you should set `white-space:normal` on them explicitly.

Comment: @MrLister That is true. I didn't mention that explicitly because I wasn't sure what the OP would actually be doing inside the parent container, like images or something. But thanks for bringing that to the attention.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/hd8Bm/9/

`display:inline` was not necessary.

Comment: Not exactly. As I wrote, having a smaller container as its content elements... some will break into a new line But they have to be in one

Comment: on your example, reducing the containers width will end in a break into new line of the second content element

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you want to hide something, or prevent it from being clicked, position:absolute may work, on newer browsers, I mean. 
 float:left is sometimes helpful, too.